# Unable to load jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using Ubuntu Linux, Apache 2 and jQuery in file format to learn how the get method works. But I receive the following error : 
ReferenceError: $ is not defined. 
My question is how am I able to load jquery. The jquery.js, index.php and process.php are placed in the root of a same folder.
my index.php file's code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>myInfo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //jquery part to sent and recieve data and print it
            function jqget(){
                  var get = $.get("localhost:8080/myInfo/process.php",
                  {name : "ESTRAGON"}, 
                  function (data){console.log(data);
                });
            }

        jqget();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your jquery path, is it correct?

Comment: to check if the source of the included jquery, open the page source and click on the jquery.js link

Comment: Or open the browser's dev console and see if a 404 is reported for jquery.js.

Comment: What would be the correct way of expressing this path : /var/www/myInfo/ ?????

Comment: The requested URL /var/www/myInfo/jquery.js was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the path to your jQuery, is incorrect. Try to use the CDN:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>myInfo</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //jquery part to sent and recieve data and print it
            function jqget(){
                var get = $.get("localhost:8080/myInfo/process.php",
                    {name : "ESTRAGON"}, 
                    function (data){console.log(data);}
                );
            }

            jqget();
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am actually trying to use the jQuery file that I've downloaded. What would be the way to do it in Linux? except that of using a CDN!

Comment: loading a file in to a browser is not a os or browser dependent thing. open the console (ctrl+shift+J on chrome) and see if  the network->scripts tab is showing a 404 in red for the jquery.js

Comment: ROX: Yes, I recieve the following error : GET http://localhost:8080/var/www/myInfo/jquery.js     [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]   . Would you please tell me what to do?

Comment: @astro: Could you help me PLEASE.

Comment: @KooroshSadeghi What is the address of your page you are viewing?

Comment: Dear ROX: I've been disconnected for 2 days but, the very last made me think about it more. My problem is been taken care of , thanks to your help. THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH.